# Not able to proxy pass AWS Kibana to nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kibana-4

I'm using AWS kibana to search and view the logs that Logstash has indexed. Right now i'm using the default URL from AWS and is only restricted to my IP address. I need to proxy_pass it through nginx, i tried to follow this doc: https://sysadmins.co.za/aws-access-kibana-5-behind-elb-via-nginx-reverse-proxy-on-custom-dns/

But kibana is not loading. I'm getting the following error:

```
Kibana: Not Found
Error: Not Found
    at respond (http://IP/index.js?_b=7562:85344:15)
    at checkRespForFailure (http://IP/index.js?_b=7562:85312:7)
    at http://IP/index.js?_b=7562:83950:7
    at wrappedErrback (http://IP/index.js?_b=7562:20902:78)
    at wrappedErrback (http://IP/index.js?_b=7562:20902:78)
    at wrappedErrback (http://IP/index.js?_b=7562:20902:78)
    at http://IP/index.js?_b=7562:21035:76
    at Scope.$eval (http://IP/index.js?_b=7562:22022:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http://IP/index.js?_b=7562:21834:31)
    at Scope.$apply (http://IP/index.js?_b=7562:22126:24)
```

Adding Nignx conf:

```
    server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
      server_name kibana.mydomain.com;

      # for elb health checks
      location /status {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/ ;
      }

      location / {
        proxy_set_header Host search-aws-es.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP <public-ip-for-instance>;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
        proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
        proxy_set_header Authorization "";

        proxy_pass https://search-aws-es.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com/_plugin/kibana/;
        proxy_redirect https://search-aws-es.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com/_plugin/kibana/ http://<public-ip-for-instance>/kibana/;
      }

      location ~ (/app/kibana|/app/timelion|/bundles|/es_admin|/plugins|/api|/ui|/elasticsearch) {
         proxy_pass              http://search-aws-es.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com;
         proxy_set_header        Host $host;
         proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Kibana 4 and Kibana 5 could be different. So i assume your url is hitting the private IP of the machine in `http://IP/index.js?_b=7562:85344:15`?

Comment: @TarunLalwani No in the error message it showing MY puplic ip.

Comment: And what is the main URL your are opening? Also please add your full nginx config

Comment: @TarunLalwani added nginx conf

Answer (score 2):

On your last location block, add /_plugin/kibana, that fixed it for me.

My working setup (with a VPC based ES but that shouldn't change much as long as you authorize the IP of your proxy within the ES access policy):

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  kibana.mydomain.com

  location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    # proxy_set_header Host https://asdfadsfasdfasdf.regionxxx.es.amazonaws.com;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
    proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
    proxy_set_header Authorization "";
    proxy_pass              https://asdfadsfasdfasdf.regionxxx.es.amazonaws.com/_plugin/kibana/;
  }

  location ~ (/_plugin/kibana|/app/kibana|/app/timelion|/bundles|/es_admin|/plugins|/api|/ui|/elasticsearch) {
    proxy_pass              https://asdfadsfasdfasdf.regionxxx.es.amazonaws.com;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header        Authorization  "";
  }
}
```